# recon-ng syntax error

Tags: recon-ng

When running Recon-ng after setting every option correctly, I'm getting the following error

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/usr/share/recon-ng/recon/core/module.py", line 342, in do_run
    self.run()
  File "/usr/share/recon-ng/recon/core/module.py", line 336, in run
    self.module_run(*params)
  File "/home/kali/.recon-ng/modules/recon/ports-hosts/ssl_scan.py", line 26, in module_run
    ip, port = host.split(':')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
------------------------------------------------------------
[!] Something broken? See https://github.com/lanmaster53/recon-ng/wiki/Troubleshooting#issue-reporting.
```

Comment: *"after setting every option correctly"* - which is a claim without proof. Based on the error shown on some place "ip:port" was expected but not given.

Comment: Always provide the command you used along with the error message. How are we supposed to help?